# Python: Same or different method names in MVC

Tags: python, model-view-controller, naming-conventions

I am currently writing a booking system and I'm following MVC.
My question is what is considered a better practice:

1. All methods from the different packages along the line of a single operation to have the same names
2. Come up with different names for each method?

To clarify my questions, here is an example:
When booking an appointment, that's the current sequence:

1. The toplevel windows calls `root.book_appointment()` (root is the "controller" of the view package)
2. root calls `controller.book_appointment()`
3. controller `calls model.book_appointment()`
4. model calls `database.book_appointment()`

I tried to find a convention or opinions somewhere, but I could not find anything.
One way, everything has the same names, even though there is always an identifier before the method call(root, controller, model, database etc). On the other hand for every operation that starts from a panel I need to come up with another 5 method names until I reach the database.

Thanks a lot in advance for your time and answers!

Tried googling for answers, but nothing came up. Most answers were for methods with same names and different parameters.

Comment: Did you use a framework or is everything custom built? What I'd do is look at the best practices done in django/flask/fast api/... (the latter two e.g. in combination with sqlalchemy). Usually they don't really do it that strict.

Comment: Currently I'm finishing the offline version. In other words, all I've used so far is tkinter for GUI and sqlite for db. After everything works fine I will migrate to PostgreSQL and django. I just wanted everything with the pc/offline app to work fine and be finished, so I won't have to worry about it when adding web app.